# Clarification of DecimalFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits() method argument

Tags: java, formatting, decimalformat

Directly from this [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#applyLocalizedPattern%28java.lang.String%29):

> setMaximumIntegerDigits
>
> public void setMaximumIntegerDigits(int newValue)
>
> Sets the maximum number of digits allowed in the integer portion of a
> number. For formatting numbers other than BigInteger and BigDecimal
> objects, the lower of newValue and 309 is used. Negative input values
> are replaced with 0.

In this context, what does "the lower of newValue and 309 is used" mean? Considering that newValue is the int passed as an argument and 309 I have no idea what they are referring to..
Any clue would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about asking how an api behaves and not the problem.

Comment: @NarendraPathai thanks for your feedback. However using API is part of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the source code for `DecimalFormat` you will find

```
// Upper limit on integer and fraction digits for a Java double
static final int DOUBLE_INTEGER_DIGITS  = 309;
```

It's the number of digits possible to represent before the decimal point in a Java `double`, insofar as the allowable range of a double is [-1.79769313486232e308 ; 1.79769313486232e308 ] (notice the exponents).

Cheers,